# implementing Google Authenticator in java

Tags: java, android, google-authenticator

i want to implement Google authenticator in my Android application , actually i want to insert a Serial generated by google (the serial code generated when you want to change your gmail to 2 steps authentification or QR Code) and then generate the validation code as Google Authenticator do but i want to do it in my application without using Google Authenticator App...
i hope that someone can help me